# People Picker not showing some users from Azure AD / 365 users

Tags: sharepoint-online

Currently when we use the People Picker Web Part, some users just cannot be found. What could be the cause, and where do we start investigating?

Comment: are you talking about default OOUT People web part?

Comment: Yes the OOTB one

Comment: What type of users aren't appearing members or guest accounts?

Comment: @CallumCrowley Members. But some members do appear though. Very weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `Email` field was empty.

SharePoint People Picker Web Part uses the `Email` field and not the `User principal name`

[image]